# Cakephp 3 how to set maximum number of selected option in multiple select?

Tags: php, forms, validation, cakephp-3.0

I would like to set a rule to limit the number of option visitors can select in a field multiple select.

I tried this, but it doesn't work

```
$validator
    ->add('colors._ids', [
        'multiple'=>[
            'rule'=>['multiple', ['max'=>3]],
            'message'=>'Please select only one color'
        ]
    ])
    ->requirePresence('colors._ids', 'create');
//    ->allowEmpty('colors._ids');

return $validator;
```

In the view the field is displayed like that:

```
echo $this->Form->input('colors._ids', ['options' => $colors, 'multiple' => true]);
```

Using debugtoolkit I can read:

- _serialize(array)
- car(array)
- new(true)
- accessible(array)
- properties(array)
- dirty(array)
- original(empty)
- virtual(empty)
- errors(array)
- **colors._ids(array)**
- **_required This field is required**
- repository Cars
- users(array)
- colors(array)

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Do you get any errors back when you submit the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem to you and to solve it I ended up using a [custom validation rule](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#custom-validation-rules).

So for example:

```
->add('tablename', 'custom', [
            'rule' => function($value) {
                return (bool)(is_array($value['_ids']) && count($value['_ids']) === 3);
            },
            'message' => 'Please select 3.'
        ]);
```

This rule will make sure the user selects 3 items from the select. No more no less, I'm sure you could adapt this for your problem.